# How do I show notifications even if the app is not running

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I need show notifications as per user chosen interval. I have to show these notification even if the app is closed. I have used AlarmManager to schedule the repeat notifications. When the app is running or in try, it is working fine but if the app is killed, its not working.

```
public static void setRecurringNotification(Context context, long scTime) {
    System.out.println("Inside setRecurringNotification()");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            NotificationReceiver.class);

    pendingIntentNotification = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + scTime, scTime,
            pendingIntentNotification);
}// End of setRecurringAlarm()
```

Below is the NotificationReceiver class:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    public static void sendNotification(Context context, MyMessage msg) {
        System.out.println("sendNotification(): " + msg.getId());

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(msg.getTitle())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(
                        new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg.getContent()))
                .setContentText(msg.getContent())
                .setSound(soundUri);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }// End of sendNotification

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Inside NotificationReceiver.onReceive...");
        try {

            new NotifyUser(context).execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }

    private class NotifyUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private Context context;

        public NotifyUser(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            SQLHelper sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(context);
            try {
                MyMessage msg = sqlHelper.getRandomMyMessageFromDB();
                if (null != msg)
                    sendNotification(context, msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Android Service to perform background operations when the app is closed. For more detailed information refer to [Android Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Dont we required BroadcastReceiver? Actually I tried calling Service from my NotificationReceiver class. But it didn't give the result as I expected.

Comment: BroadcastReceiver you have to use if you have to perform some action based on System events. Else Service will be sufficient. Follow the official docs for service. Understand it well and it will work. Millions of developers are using the same method. Rest I will post some links if I will get example for the same.